# Remove %20 From the Url

Tags: c#

I have a problem:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath)
```

This statement gives %20 for me. I want to remove this. Is there any way other than replace?

Comment: Why can't you just replace it?

Comment: Do you want to remove it? Or replace it with a space?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use HttpUtility.UrlDecode - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx

Answer (score 11):

You can use [HTTPUtility.URLDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) to remove %20 and any other encoded characters.  It won't actually remove it, but rather, replace it with a space, as that is what it represents.  If you actually want it removed completely, you have to use replace.

Answer (score 6):

[UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode`*<sup>[[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)]</sup>* in lieu of a string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following regex: `s/%20/ /g`